# Calculate date range between two rows

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench

I have a table where I have materials cost which get change based on the dates and get recorded into the table.
Please see below image for the more details.
[image]

If you see input table, in first row material XYZ cost is 43.14 from '6/29/2018' to'12/31/9999' and in second row again cost of the material get change to 44 and now datefrom is '8/3/2018' and so on, now I want to get the date range(dateto) for the first row based on the second row datefrom which will be less than one day from the second datefrom ('8/2/2018'), highlighted in required out put table.

I have tried inner join and other queries but unable to get the required output.

Comment: Your question indicates you want to calculate cost but you dont supply any formula. Instead your table shows dateto changing values but you dont explain how that occured? Please edit your question to help explain your problem. Also show any SQL you tried.

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: @StephenQuan I have edited the question , let me know if still it is not clear to you.

Comment: Your real question is how to populate "dateto" using "datefrom"  from the subsequent row (minus 1 day). That would have been more clear. People would come up with solutions much faster. I dont think you should use the COST column finding that solution. You should be solving the problem using primary keys or rowid. Please explain some of your attempts at solving this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try with this?

```
WITH TEMP AS
(
    SELECT 
        RANK() OVER ( PARTITION BY MATERIAL ORDER BY DATEFROM ASC) AS ASC_RANK,
        RANK() OVER ( PARTITION BY MATERIAL ORDER BY DATEFROM DESC) AS DES_RANK,
        MATERIAL, COST, DATEFROM, DATETO
    FROM 
)
SELECT MATERIAL, COST, DATEFROM, DATETO
FROM TEMP
WHERE DES_RANK = 1 

UNION ALL 

SELECT T1.MATERIAL, T1.COST, T1.DATEFROM, (T2.DATETO - 1) AS DATETO
FROM TEMP T1
JOIN TEMP T2 ON T1.MATERIAL = T2.MATERIAL AND T1.ASC_RANK = (T2.ASC_RANK + 1)
```